# How to prevent the loss of form data when session expires?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, session, timeout

### QUESTION

Using **ASP.NET VB** and/or **JavaScript** how can a user be prevented from losing form data when a session expires?

---

**The Problem**

Currently when a user is filling out form data for a period longer than the session timeout period all form data is lost on post due to session expiry.

Client side actions such as typing **DO NOT** reset the session timeout period.

---

**Ideas**

I would like to know ways to prevent this problem occurring.

- My initial idea is a notification message warning of pending expiry
  and an option to reset session timer.
- An alternate idea is a way to pass a **key press** or **mouse movement** to the server to cause an auto refresh of session timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION 1 : KEEP SESSION ALIVE**

On way of to solve your problem is to keep session alive while the form is opened. I'm sure there many ways to 'keep alive' user's session. For me, I use generic handler and this work fine at least in my requirement.

First, create a generic handler and enter code as below:

```
Public Class KeepSessionAlive
    Implements IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState

    Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
        context.Session("KeepSessionAlive") = DateTime.Now
    End Sub

    ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Make sure your generic handler class implements `IRequiresSessionState` as above.

Then in you form page, use `jQuery.post` to post request the above handler at time interval of you choice. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        setInterval(function () { $.post('<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/KeepSessionAlive.ashx")%>'); }, 10000); ' 10 secs interval
        });
</script>
```

While user is on the form, the POST requests will keep refreshing user's session just like normal page requests and therefore, IIS will keep on reseting the session timeout.

**SOLUTION 2 : ALERT USER BEFORE TIMEOUT**

Another way is to alert user when session is about to end. This can be achieved simply by using plain javascript alone. I used this method few years back so pardon my scripting.

Create a javascript method :

```
function sessionTimeout(n) {
    setTimeout("alertSessionTimeout()", (n - 1) * 60 * 1000);
}

function alertSessionTimeout() {
    var answer = confirm("Your session is about to expire in 1 minute.\n\n
                          Click 'OK' to extend your session.\n
                          Click 'Cancel' to terminate you session immediately.");
    if (answer == true)
        window.location = location.href; 
    else {
        window.top.location = 'logout.aspx';
    }
}
```

On your form page, just enter onload script on your body tag:

```
<body onload="sessionTimeout(<%=session.Timeout %>)">
```

So, if your timeout setting is 10 minutes, user will be alerted on the 9th minute. Of course, you might want to change the code when user click OK button. My code above will refresh the page and that definitely not what you want to do, or else, user's data will be lost. You can use the generic handler as in SOLUTION 1 above to reset the session and call `sessionTimeout` again to reset client side timeout countdown.

Answer (score 0):

In the age of single page apps if you need to work with old school approach, my advise would be to create Ajax request that constantly updates data in your website or just checks for session expiration (probably request itself would prevent that). But if it happens and you receive session expired message you could just show some login popup for user to login without leaving actual page.

Comment: The problem is the data on the page needs to be secure so using a session timeout for its intended purpose is also required.

Comment: Ok so other approach is similar to your initial idea: while loading page create a javascript variable with a time limit user has before his session is expired. Then run some js function on timeout every few seconds to see if time elapsed since last refresh has reached session expiration timeout.If you detect this situation then you can something like a) disable post buttons b) display some popup with login option c) open popup page with your login screen etc.

Comment: The login popup is a good idea.  You could use an ajax call in the onsubmit event for the form to see if the user is still logged in.  If they aren't, cancel the submit and show the login popup.  After they have logged in they can then submit the form.